# How to align numbers after decimal in C++ output

Tags: c++, output, cout

*Edited*

Hey guys I am making a small program to collect user input as a total then breaking it down into different taxes. I have the program set to have only two numbers after the decimal using setprecision. I am wondering if there is a way to make sure no matter what number is entered it is always aligned by its last decimal so it forms a perfect column? Right now if you run the program the numbers are right aligned but since the taxes generated are smaller, they don't line up underneath each other correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

To be more specific: No matter how many figures the "Total Collected" input is, for example four ($2,500) or five ($25,000), I am wanting the answers generated by my program to align properly still. I know setw can work but that is only if it is made to work for one type of number, such as five figure numbers.

Here is the code I am using via XCode:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    string M;
    int Y;
    double T;
    double S;
    double C;
    double A;
    double O;


    cout << "Month: ";
    cin >> M;

    cout << "Year: ";
    cin >> Y;

    cout << "-----------------------------------\n";

    cout << "Total Collected:          $";
    cin >> T;

    S = (T / 1.06);
    C = (S * .02);
    A = (S * .04);
    O = (C + A);

    cout << "Sales:                    $" << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << S;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "County Sales Tax:         $" << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << C;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "State Sales Tax:          $" << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << A;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Total Sales Tax:          $" << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << O;
    cout << "\n";







    //std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `std::setw`?

Comment: Regarding the dupe's answer, just omit the `setfill('0')`, if you want spaces (`' '`) instead.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, what is your problem? mavra pei or whatever your name is? None of these answers so far help my problem nor solve it.

Comment: Ive tried using setw and played with different spaces, but it doesnt change with the amount of numbers used in the total. If its a four figure number ONLY, you ca use setw to make sure all of the answers generated align properly. I am wondering how to make sure if you use a four figure number or five figure or even six that all the answers still align the same.